Solar-PuTTY keeps showing "Pageant: Couldn't load this key (unable to open file)" when begins to connect
I use Solar-PuTTY 4.1.0.0 on Windows 11.
Every time I use it connect to a server with ssh, it always shows this:

However,

The connection is successful.
Pageant also loads the key correctly (the key is shown in Pageant Key List).

It seems there is nothing wrong, but the "Couldn't load this key" message still always appears. I don't even know what key it failed to load.
I try pure PuTTY, it works well and no "Couldn't load this key" message.
I found this question, but I don't think that's my question:
Pageant: Couldn't load this key (unable to open file)
I also tried using Process Monitor as one of the answers suggested, but I didn't see anything wrong. It tries to load the current key file.

